# Code showing wrong output

Tags: c#, sorting, insertion-sort

I have developed a program in c# which is doing "Insertion Sort", the code takes in a max value for the elements and the values of the elements and then one by one shows the steps of sorted values.

**Code:**

```
    static void insertionSort(int[] ar)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < ar.Length; i++)
        {
            int temp = ar[i];
            int j = i - 1;

            while (j >= 0 && ar[j] > temp)
            {
                ar[j + 1] = ar[j];

                foreach (int val in ar)
                    Console.Write(val + " ");
                Console.WriteLine();

                j--;
            }
        }


    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {

        int ar_size;
        ar_size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] ar = new int[ar_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++)
        {
            ar[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        }

        insertionSort(ar);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**The Sample Input That I Give:**

```
5
2 4 6 8 3
```

**The Output That Comes:**
[image]

**Can anyone explain me why is this happening!**

**Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)**

Comment: Unless I'm being really dumb this afternoon your insertionSort method is just going to write over things rather than sort them as when the value in one index is higher than the value in the next you don't swap them, you just overwrite the lower value.

Comment: how can this can be implemented? @Kobunite

Comment: http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/Insertion_Sort.html

Comment: Your while loop is 'making room' but you never copy `temp` to its final place.

Comment: Hint: test it with `int[] ar = { 4, 6, 1, 9, 7 };` instead of `ReadLine()`

Comment: I was just about to answer, then I noticed that @Gopesh Sharma has posted the answer in that link. :-)

Comment: try putting ar[j+1]=temp below the ending brace } of your while after the j--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the problems with your sort itself, the reason for the strange numbers in your result is that you use `Console.Read` very wrong. It returns the ASCII value of the character entered by the user. Furthermore, it will return the ASCII values for all entered characters, not only for the numbers.

So, the first call to `Console.Read()` will return 50 (ASCII value of `'2'`).
The second call will return 32 (ASCII value of a space).
The third call will return 52 (ASCII value of `'4'`).
etc.

To fix this, initialize `ar` like this:

```
var numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++)
    ar[i] = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[i]);
```

Please note that this code lacks error handling. It will throw an exception in the followin circumstances:

1. The user entered anything besides spaces and numbers
2. The user entered less numbers than he specified in the first line

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui: My answer contains code that fixes this particular problem.